# Get rid of 'is defined but never used' in function parameter

Tags: typescript, eslint

I am getting the error/warning from ESLint that `'d' is declared but never used`, however I need this type declaration in function parameter to avoid subsequent TypeScript errors. Is there a way of solving this problem/warning except changing the rules in `.eslintrc.json` file for `no-unused-vars`?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to use the _TypeScript_ version of the rule, ESLint's rules aren't aware of types: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unused-vars.md

Answer (score 26):

In your `.eslintrc.json` add `"no-unused-vars": ["error", { "argsIgnorePattern": "^_" }]` to `"rules"`. Mine looks like this:

```
...
"rules": {
        "no-unused-vars": ["error", { "argsIgnorePattern": "^_" }],
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["error", { "argsIgnorePattern": "^_" }],
    },
...
```

Now you should be able to add an underscore to the start of your variable declarations and it should avoid the error message.

Ex:

`const myFunc = (c, b) => {}` would be `const myFunc = (_c, _b) => {}`

You can also take a look ate [argsignorepattern](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#argsignorepattern) in the ESLint documentation.

---

I believe if you are using the `typescript` you might also have to add `"@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["error", { "argsIgnorePattern": "^_" }]"`

Comment: Thank you a lot! Actually 'no-unused-vars': 1 just replaces the error with warning but following the link you mentioned and setting ["error", { "argsIgnorePattern": "^_" }] helped!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: @spatak Did you just set `"rules": {"no-unused-vars": ["error", { "argsIgnorePattern": "^_" }],}` ?

Comment: yes. I added it above all of my over rules

Answer (score 8):

i think this is the shortest answer

```
//.eslintrc.json

...
"rules": {
    "no-unused-vars": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "error",
  },
...
```